# Error in projecting SpatialPolygonsDataFrame from geographical coordinate to UTM

Tags: r, r-sp, rgdal

I would like to project the coordinates of the 2012 Peruvian census to work with another raster layer that has the following coordinates reference system :

> "+proj=utm +zone=18 +south +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ".

The answer of the post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31743/projecting-sp-objects-in-r did not work in my case.

```
crs(census)
```

> CRS arguments:
>    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

```
newCRScensus=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=18 +south +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ") 
projcensus=spTransform(census,crs=newCRScensus)
```

> Error in spTransform(census, crs = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=18 +south +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ")) : 
>     second argument needs to be of class CRS

I don't understand the error message since the second argument is indeed of class CRS.

Any suggestions for another way of projecting the geographical coordinates is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `spTransform` is called `CRSobj`, not `crs`, so the right call should be either

```
projcensus=spTransform(census, newCRScensus)
```

or

```
projcensus=spTransform(census, CRSobj = newCRScensus)
```